# What is the meaning of "bhīma-karmā vṛkodaraḥ" in Gita 1.15?

Tags: mahabharata, bhagavad-gita, sanskrit

In Gita 1.15 Bhīma is called "bhīma-karmā vṛkodaraḥ", or something along the lines of "tremendous-deeds wolf-bellied".

1. Are there any particular stories about Bhima's tremendous deeds and voracious hunger behind this?
2. What is the case of "karmā"? It looks related to the root "karman" but doesn't seem to be identical to any case of its declension.

Comment: Karman masculine becomes karmā

Comment: Bhima is the main character in mahabharat after krishna.. Because all the 5 great warriors of that time killed by bhima, Hidimbha, bakashura,Jaarasandha, Kichaka and duryodhana(main villain of mahabharata) killed by bhima.Yes in ekka chakkranagara he did go to everyones house with big pot for begging.. the pot as huge as one potters house. He used to take more share of food out of his five brothers because of variousous appetite. why he did this because he is able to ingest poison with out any effect. like kallakoota poison which duryodhaa gave in his childhood.

Comment: He did this to use whenever vironchana the minister of duryodhana mixes poison in  the food. he did consume all of the food without leaving anything to his brothers because it was laced with poison in vana vratha wax palace plot by duryodhana. that is why he got is name vrkodhara.

Comment: Regarding Karma vrkodhara. he was astitute in his prescribed duties as specified in shastras. he never deviates from this. He was doing Achamana(sip of water with keshavas name after consuming food) even during danger of being attacked by bakashura.. He is main person behind pancharata agama being practised by vaishnavite even today. because during his years as main prince in yudhistra ruling he established pancharatara doctrine to be followed by masses

Comment: As a shatriya dhrama one should not surrender because its equal to death.. better get matyr dom instead of surrender, that is why inthe war, Ashattama acharya thrown one missile Narayanastra. the speciality of this weapon is this will burn all the enimies one who is the battle field and not in the battle field also. Lord krishna sees one ashukini sena was destroyed by missile, so he immediately asks all the pandava soliders to leave the weapons in their hand and bow to Narayana missile.. so that it would spare all the soldiers who had surrender

Comment: . so krishna was able to save the remaining pandava army like this, but bhima refuse to surrender to Narayanastra.. as per shatriya dharma.. it starts burning Bhimas head on seeing this arjun jumps to bhimas rescue he launches varuna astra to subside the burning and also removes the weapon from bhimas hand forcefully.. so it spared bhima..

Comment: he will stick to his karma niyamana even during danger to life.. All this was stated by  Sriman Madhvacharya himsel in his Mahabharata tatparya nirnaya scripture (MBTN) he is kaliyuga avatara of bhima.

Comment: @Fernando, here Bhima is addressed as Vrikodara, it means, he who has kept in his belly that particular fire which is able to burn the whole world into ashes. So in this way,Bhimas parakrama as a great warrior is being established as such.